# Microsoft Sync Framework Guideline

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a confusion in my mind about Microsoft sync framework that can it sync the updated entries through the .sdf file. And where can i get the proper way to store an entry to the .sdf file i have tried doing so on my local PC's but the data was not transferred So can anyone guide me though the whole process or give me a link or site from where i can get the solution......

Answer (score 0):

Sql Compact is supported in Sync Fx and it's pretty straight forward to get it working.

if you have installed Sync Fx, the help file included in the install already includes several walkthroughs on setting up sync using Sql Compact.

what errors are you getting?